# Swagger (Swashbuckle) on ASP.NET Core MVC targeting .Net Framework 4.6.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I am migrating WebApi2 project to MVC6. 
As we have other dependencies written in .NET 4.6.1 we need to target same version.

```
"frameworks": {
"net461": {}}
```

I have added dependencies:

```
"Swashbuckle": "5.3.2",
```

But the problem is that there is no way to hook up/register it to the ASP.NET Core MVC.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Please note, there is no MVC6 anymore. The MVC6 tag is reserved for a possible future version based on the old ASP.NET MVC Webstack. What you are referring is now called ASP.NET Core MVC  and uses the version number 1.0, since it's a complete rewrite based on .NET Core and not compatible with the old ASP.NET MVC webstack

Answer (score 5):

With ASP.NET Core you should use the this port of Swashbuckle  https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy

Than you will Add/Use extensions methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ... Configure MVC services ...

    // Inject an implementation of ISwaggerProvider with defaulted   settings applied
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ... Enable MVC middleware ...

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
}
```

Comment: Any good ideas as to why the extension methods for UseSwagger() and useSwaggerUI() are unavailable? I have tried referencing using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore;/using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;/using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI;

Answer (score 2):

The 5.x version of Swashbuckle do not support ASP.NET Core MVC. You have to use the new Swashbuckle 6.x version which has support for ASP.NET Core.

The only version which supports ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM is `6.0.0-beta901`.

So you need to add this to your project.json file

```
"Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta901"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swashbuckle version that is compatible with .Net Framework 4.6. is `5.6.0`

Comment: Could you see xml documentation generated in swagger-ui, <summary></summary>?